# Close modal on click

Tags: angular

I have a Model with custom buttons

```
 <modal #modal>
        <modal-header [show-close]="true">
           Header Text
        </modal-header>
        <modal-body>
          Body Text
        </modal-body>
        <modal-footer>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="modal.dismiss()">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="SaveProject()">Ok</button>
        </modal-footer>
    </modal>
```

On the component side I have code for SaveProject()

```
 SaveProject() {
//      Some Logic

    }
```

I want to close the modal after the logic is complete. For this, I implemented this in the component page

```
import { ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
```

In export class I have

```
   modal: ModalComponent;
```

And in my click event I have

```
SaveProject() {
//      Some Logic
this.modal.close();
    }
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ViewChild` like mentioned.

```
@ViewChild('modal')
modal: ModalComponent;
```

Then you can use `close` or even `dismiss` if you want, depending on your use case:

```
SaveProject() {
   this.modal.close();
   // this.modal.dismiss();
}
```

More info [**here**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bs3-modal), excerpt from page:

> ```
> close(value?: any): Promise<any>
> ```
>
> Closes the modal. Causes onClose to be emitted. Returns a promise that resolves the value passed to close when the modal is completely hidden.
>
> ```
> dismiss(): Promise
> ```
>
> Dismisses the modal. Causes onDismiss to be emitted. Returns a promise that resolves when the modal is completely hidden.